# Vertx JDBC client queryWithParams - how to add a list?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, vert.x

I have SQL query with condition `currency in ?`
and I'm using vertx JDBC client `queryWithparams` method, which receives query parameters in JsonArray.

How can I pass my list of possible `currency` values to the query?
I tried `new JsonArray().add(new JsonArray(currencies)` but got exception

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't add a List as a query parameter with the generic Vertx JDBC client, but since you're using Postgres there is a Postgres-specific library called vertx-pg-client that you can use. I implemented roughly the same query as you did with this code:

```
List<String> currencies = whatever();
String uri = "your-uri";
String query = "select from table where currency = any($1)";
PgConnection.connect(vertx, uri, connectionResult -> {
    if (connectionResult.failed()) {
        // handle
    } else {
        PgConnection connection = connectionResult.result();
        Tuple params = Tuple.of(currencies);

        doQuery(query, connection, params).setHandler(queryResult -> {
            connection.close();
            msg.reply(queryResult.result());
        });
    }
});

    private Future<String> doQuery(String sql, PgConnection connection, Tuple params) {
        Promise<String> promise = Promise.promise();
        connection.preparedQuery(sql, params, res -> {
            if (res.failed()) {
                // log
                promise.fail(res.cause());
            } else {
                RowSet<Row> rowSet = res.result();
                // do something with the rows and construct a return object (here, a string)
                String result = something;
                promise.complete(result);
            }
        });
        return promise.future();
    }
```

All credit goes to @tsegismont who helped me with the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59758155/how-to-use-a-list-as-a-parameter-source-for-sql-queries-with-vertx-jdbc-client).

Comment: I'm getting following exception by applying above approach:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Values [[]] cannot be coerced to [String[]]
any idea ?

Comment: What is the type of object you're wrapping in Tuple? Is it List<String>?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options.

If you want to support multiple databases, you'll have to expand your expression yourself:

```
"... currency IN (" + String.join(",", Collections.nCopies(currencies.size(), "?")) + ")"
```

If you support only PostreSQL, you can use `ANY` operator instead:

```
WHERE currency = ANY(?)
```

Comment: The first option will not allow me to create the query in advance

The second (PSQL only is good for me) - I still don't understand how do I put the list inside JsonArray

Comment: When you bind arguments, don't use JsonArray, but a regular Java one.

Comment: Vertx API allows to use JsonArray only

Comment: You really need to expand your question with some code example of what you're doing. Especially what lib you use for DB, and of what version. Thanks.

Comment: As I told in the question, I'm using Vertx JDBC client. And my question is about https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/sql/SQLConnection.html#updateWithParams-java.lang.String-io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray-io.vertx.core.Handler- method