# How to use a list as a parameter source for SQL queries with Vertx JDBC Client?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, vert.x

I have a Vert.x web application that needs to query an AWS RDS instance running Postgres 10.7. The Vert.x JDBC client is `io.vertx:vertx-jdbc-client:3.8.4`. I want to query a table with the constraint that a certain column's value is included in a set of values:

`select from table where column in/any (?)`

I followed the Vertx documentation, which says to create a `JsonArray` and populate it with the values to inject into the query. The column is of type `text` and the list that I want to match on is a Java `ArrayList<String>`. My query code looks like:

```
String sql = "SELECT a FROM table WHERE col IN (?)";
List<String> values = someObject.someField();

            sqlClient.getConnection(connectionResult -> {
                if (connectionResult.failed()) {
                    // handle
                } else {
                    SQLConnection connection = connectionResult.result();

                    JsonArray params = new JsonArray()
                            .add(values);
                    connection.queryWithParams(sql, params, queryResult -> {
                       if (queryResult.failed()) {
                           // handle
                       } else {
                           // parse
                       }
                    });
                }
            });
```

The query fails with the error: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.`

I know that in the worst case, I can create a literal SQL string `where col in (?, ?, ?, ..., ?)` and add each String from the list to a `JsonArray`, but there must be a way to just add the `ArrayList<String>` as a parameter and keep the query simple. How can I specify a list of values to match against in my query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Vert.x JDBC Client does not support array parameters in queries.

However it is possible with the [Vert.x Pg Client](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-pg-client/java/), which does not depend on JDBC. You need to modify your query first:

```
SELECT a FROM table WHERE col = ANY(?)
```

Then:

```
pgClient.preparedQuery(query, Tuple.of(possibleValues), collector, handler);
```

Comment: I found that I needed to cast the array argument in the query, and use `$1` instead of `?`, like so:

`SELECT a FROM table WHERE col = ANY($1::text[])`

I also needed to convert my list of possible values to array for the Tuple. After that it worked.