# Vertx - How to pass ArrayList to SELECT query with IN

Tags: java, vert.x, vert.x-webclient

I have a SELECT statement like `SELECT * FROM table where id=? and key IN (?,?..?)`.
For INSERT,UPDATE we have this batchWithParams, how can I do this for SELECT. I am using JDBC driver for MySQL database. The array list is like so,

```
 BATCH [[100,4,11], [150,4,12]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a list as a parameter source for SQL queries with Vertx JDBC Client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59758155/how-to-use-a-list-as-a-parameter-source-for-sql-queries-with-vertx-jdbc-client)

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59758155/how-to-use-a-list-as-a-parameter-source-for-sql-queries-with-vertx-jdbc-client, the answer is valid for MySQL too

Answer (score 0):

Why not just convert the ArrayList into String? Like this:

```
 suspend fun getUsersByEmail(emails: Iterable<String>): List<User> {
    return mysqlPool.getConnectionAwait().use { conn ->
        conn.query(
            """
                SELECT * FROM users
                WHERE email IN (${emails.joinToString(separator = ", ") { "'$it'" }})
            """
        ).executeAwait().map { row ->
            User(
                row.getLong("id"),
                row.getString("email")
            )
        }
    }
}
```