# how to set string array query in vertx and execute

Tags: vert.x

1. I have input like this now i need to set this input which I receive from client side like postman:
2. how should I pass the users[] value here in tuple
3. Query("select * from USER where users in ($1);")
4. how to pass in the tuple??

Comment: client.preparedQuery("select * from USER where users in ($1);").execute(Tuple.of(users[])) in the tuple how to pass the users array where the input is getting  from client side

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a list as a parameter source for SQL queries with Vertx JDBC Client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59758155/how-to-use-a-list-as-a-parameter-source-for-sql-queries-with-vertx-jdbc-client)