# How to run prepared Postgres query in vert.x with an IN ($1) parameter?

Tags: kotlin, vert.x

Given this SQL query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

with the `(1, 2, 3)` being a `List<Int>` of variable length, how can I bind the parameter with the vert.x Reactive Postgres client?

In the nodejs pg-promise client, it works like this:

```js
await db.any('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IN ($1:list)', [ [1, 2, 3] ])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56966692/vertx-jdbc-client-querywithparams-how-to-add-a-list/56986084#56986084

Comment: Not clear, if this question is even relevant to database, or is it a pure React question...

Comment: @vitaly-t It's totally unrelated to pg-promise, just used that here as an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up changing the query, replacing `user_id IN ($1)` with `user_id = ANY($1)`, binding an `IntArray` as as a single parameter